# When Redis node goes down, I get a lot of "System.ObjectDisposedException" from StackExchange.Redis (in the pool?)

Tags: c#, .net, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am running locally (in docker) a cluster of Redis servers with one as the master. I want to test what happens when one goes down. So i stopped the node `docker stop <node_name>`. When i do this, I suddenly see a ton of these errors:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.Net.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.Net.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.IO.Pipelines.dll
```

These get thrown even if my code is not using the client at all (but after it's been connected and given a `ConnectionMultiplexer` for the first time).

My best guess is that it's checking the connections in the pool to see if they're still good and when it finds they're not, these errors start occurring.

But I can't find anywhere that I can set either a handler or callback for these errors. They just get thrown and remain uncaught.

How can I handle this? I want to catch these exceptions.

```
//Create the connection
ConnectionMultiplexer c = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379,abortConnect=false");

//THIS IS ACTUALLY WHAT CAUSES IT
c.Close(); //Passing false also causes it

//...elided...
//Wait for a bit, and suddenly errors are thrown without accessing redis again
```

This is in .Net Core 2.2

**EDIT:**

It might be a bug in StackExchange.Redis. The error doesn't happen unless I close the multiplexer. Even if I leave the node up and just close the multiplexer, the error starts occurring. It looks like the `Close` method takes a while to complete, and during that time is where it throws those exceptions.

This is the close method from StackExchange:

```
    public void Close(bool allowCommandsToComplete = true)
    {
        if (_isDisposed) return;

        OnClosing(false);
        _isDisposed = true;
        _profilingSessionProvider = null;
        using (var tmp = pulse)
        {
            pulse = null;
        }

        if (allowCommandsToComplete)
        {
            var quits = QuitAllServers();
            WaitAllIgnoreErrors(quits);
        }
        DisposeAndClearServers();
        OnCloseReaderWriter();
        OnClosing(true);
    }
```